# Spacing JavaFX LineCharts in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, parent, gridpane, sizing

So right now I am trying to write a program for displaying data in JavaFX LineCharts. My main panel is a BorderPane with some features on top/left/right/etc.. in the center of the panel I want to display the LineChart(s). At least 1 and a maximum of 4.

So I thought about setting a gridpane into the center of the main panel to achieve an outcome similar to this:

[Sample Gridpane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN27l.jpg)

My problem now is, when I try to add LineCharts to the GridPane (with .add(chart, 0, 0), the chart just wont match with the parent. The same if I continue to add more Charts. It turns out to be something like this:

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw69n.jpg)

I looked up a lot of stuff on parent matching, but somehow I am not getting anywhere :/ I´d need to know the size of the "center" of the borderpane, then I could size the LineCharts accordingly. But I cant find it... maybe someone of you has a clue?

Cheers!

Comment: Could you get the width of said pane, divide that by two, and do the same with the height? A quick google found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643125/getting-the-width-and-height-of-the-center-space-in-a-borderpane-javafx-2)

Comment: Yes I tried this, but the result is whether satisfying, nor very elegant. When I have 4 charts in the grid, I tried to set prefWidth/Height of everyone to half of the dimensions of the GridPane. Somehow the charts still have different sizes, starting with chart 1 being the biggest and chart 4 being the smallest :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener to the GridPane for the size its children elements and update the layout constraints of the child nodes based upon the size of the child element list.

[image: charts]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class GridViewer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ChartGrid grid = new ChartGrid();

        grid.getChildren().setAll(
                IntStream.range(1, 5)
                        .mapToObj(this::createLineChart)
                        .toArray(Chart[]::new)
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
        stage.show();
    }

    class ChartGrid extends GridPane {
        ChartGrid() {
            setHgap(5);
            setVgap(5);
            setPadding(new Insets(5));

            setPrefSize(500, 500);

            Bindings.size(getChildren()).addListener((observable, oldSize, newSize) -> {
                ObservableList<Node> nodes = getChildren();
                for (int i = 0; i < newSize.intValue(); i++) {
                    GridPane.setConstraints(
                            nodes.get(i),
                            i / 2, i % 2,
                            1, 1,
                            HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER,
                            Priority.ALWAYS, Priority.ALWAYS
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private Chart createLineChart(int idx) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setTitle("Chart " + idx);
        chart.setMinSize(0, 0);

        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Note:* an important part of this solution is setting the minSize of the charts to 0:

```
chart.setMinSize(0, 0);
```

This is because if you size the available area of the GridPane smaller than the sum of the min size of the charts (which is not 0 by default), then the charts will start to be drawn overlapping each other, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, this was exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question on the population of the grid:
I want to add/remove charts dynamically (==> not via .setAll stream). When I use grid.add(chart, 0, 0) eg.,  I have to specify row/column, so the outcome is the GridPane split in four squares, with one chart in the top left corner. This isn´t wrong per se, because everything fits perfectly when I have 4 charts overall. But with one chart, the chart should actually be displayed all over the GridPane. What way/methods do you reccommend to get this right?
(I also tried .getChildren.add followed by .getChildren.set, yet same outcome as above)